# Regex to capture an exact word in a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having some trouble to capture a specific string inside of a sentence.

The Regex I'm using is `\b[0-9]{9,12}\b` to capture numbers which have between 9 and 12 digits. The boundary I was using it to specify the exact number, but the problem is, when I have a number which matches with this regex followed by a dot, for example, the regex still matching and giving me much trouble.

As I searched, the problem is that `\b` uses some special characters as a separator too, right? Then is there a way to consider, for example **123456789.** a whole string and the regex will not match with that example?

Thanks !

Comment: You can use `\b(?<!\.)[0-9]{9,12}(?!\.)\b`

Comment: I just removed the "<" sign and it worked ! Probably an typing error right ? And thanks a lot !

Comment: Why replace `(?<!\.)` with `(?!\.)`? That makes no sense because a digit cannot be a dot. It must be `\b(?<!\.)[0-9]{9,12}(?!\.)\b`

Comment: It was just a question , because I'm using an online regex tester , and it accused an error on this point .

Comment: You should use .NET compatible online testers: regexhero.net, regexstorm.net, etc. Or use Ultrapico Expresso (a free tool that explains patterns like at regex101.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word boundary `\b` requires a non-word character before and after a digit (as a digit is a *word* character). As dots and commas are non-word characters, they are allowed. To make sure the digit sequence between dots is not matched, you need to use *lookarounds*.

You can use

```
\b(?<!\.)[0-9]{9,12}(?!\.)\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3C!%5C.)%5B0-9%5D%7B9%2C12%7D(%3F!%5C.)%5Cb&i=123456789.%0D%0A.123456789.%0D%0A.123456789%0D%0A123456789%0D%0A1234567890%0D%0A12345678901%0D%0A123456789012%0D%0A1234567890123)

The additional subpatterns are the lookbehind `(?<!\.)` and a lookahead `(?!\.)` that make sure there are no `.` before and after the digit sequence.

If you have `.` and `,` as decimal separators, you may want to adjust the pattern to

```
\b(?<![.,])[0-9]{9,12}(?![.,])\b
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation Wiktor ! It works !